# Discrepancy in iOS app size when in iTunes and on iDevice

Tags: ios, itunes, ipa

I'm working on an app for which I've made a release build to run on test devices. In iTunes when I go to 'get info' it says the apps size is 13megabytes.

When I install the app it says the file is closer to 40megabytes. The actual .app file is ~40 megabytes, when I zip it it's down to ~13 megabytes. Does this mean as an IPA the file will be 13 megabytes?

So if the app is put on the store will it show up as 13 megabytes or 40 megabytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will be shown as 13 mb...ipa are compressed version of the binary..which is extracted to full size during installation on device..